I overstayed 90 days in Switzerland. I have EU residency and never got any stamps in passport. Can I exit/enter at airport without trouble?
I hold a UK passport but have EU residency (portugal)
I have overstayed the 90 day period (within 180) in Switzerland but my passport did not get stamped on entry. I would like to fly out next week and come back a week later. Will the airport border control know I have overstayed and give me trouble?
Could I say I have spent some of my time here in Italy/France? Will I overstayed despite no passport stamps and flag me up?

Could I say I have spent some of my time here in Italy/France? Not if you haven’t. Lying to Immigration is not a good idea.

Flying out from which Swiss airport to which other airport?  Did you arrive in Switzerland from Portugal or from another Schengen country?

Just be aware that being sneaky at borders is incredibly difficult.  Do not try your hand unless you are a seasoned pro with decades of experience doing so.  WAIT - also take great notice of what @ave says below

@user20574 for sure - but if he's asked (by some incredible cincidence), he's cooked

The 90/180 rule isn't really enforced for legal residents, as there is no way to do so. However the authorities in Portugal might notice that you are absent, and doubt that you are indeed a resident, and not just trying to get around Schengen resitrictions.

How many days have you overstayed? Why are you spending so much time in Switzerland and how can you be away from your country of residence for so long?

Practically: there's almost no chance this will cause you issues. If you're worried, take a train to a nearby airport outside of Switzerland (eg Milan/Lyon/Stuttgart) and fly from there. If you're flying to Portugal then you won't go through passport control; if you're flying to the UK then you will. In either case, flying back into Switzerland, if you need to show your status, then if you present your passport and residence permit you will be allowed to enter unless the border guard considers that you are breaching the conditions of your residence permit and the 90/180 rule - the chances of this are minimal but never zero.
Legally: if you want to fly back into Switzerland and stay there then you should be looking at applying for residency. Any stay in Switzerland for over 90 days in a 180 day period without a valid residence permit is against the rules. You have overstayed as soon as you were in Switzerland for over 90 days in 180 without a valid Swiss residence permit. On the basis of a Portuguese residence permit you can stay in Switzerland for up to 90 days as long as the Portuguese residence permit remains valid. Note that if you have a Portuguese residence permit on the basis of being resident in Portugal but then you cease to be resident there then the permit may have lost its validity.

As a note for non-EU-residents: Absolutely do not go outside Switzerland inside Schengen if you're overstaying, instead fly directly out. If found out you will be charged not just with overstaying but illegal border crossing, a situation I observed happen exactly as described (overstayed in Switzerland, came to Munich to fly) when doing translation at the border. This is a much worse outcome for you.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Since you only hold residency of one country of the EU, you don't have the same rights as EU citizens regarding travel within the Schengen area. The Schengen area includes both Switzerland and most other EU countries (Italy, France).
This is a special case. You are allowed to enter Schengen for 90 days out of 180 days (rolling), but the one country where you reside (Portugal) is an exception and doesn't count towards the 90 days.
Since you are resident of Portugal, Portugal is the exception for you. Every day that you are in the Schengen area outside Portugal (for example, if you visit Spain), that day technically counts towards your allowance of 90 days per 180.

I would like to fly out next week and come back a week later. Will the airport border control know I have overstayed and give me trouble?

Based on anecdotal evidence, this is very unlikely. They are also unlikely to have good evidence of whether or not you have crossed land borders within the Schengen area. Therefore, they are unlikely to be confident about exactly how many of those days you have spent in Portugal.

Could I say I have spent some of my time here in Italy/France?

You should not. The 90-day per 180-day rolling total is a Schengen rule, not a Switzerland rule.
As such, it applies to the sum of the days spent in Schengen countries. The time spent in Switzerland, Italy, and France is added together.
Only time spent in your resident country, Portugal, will not count towards the total.

I would like to fly out next week and come back a week later.

I wasn't clear if you know this, but the 90-day rule counts all days in the last 180 days. This 90-day allowance will NOT reset when you fly out and back. If you have recently overstayed, you would need days to roll off your allowance before returning.
For example, if you return to Switzerland on 1st September 2024, entering Schengen, every day that you have spent in Schengen and outside Portugal  since 6th March 2024 will count towards the calculation of the 90 days.
I believe it is somewhat more likely that you will be refused entry to Schengen, rather than refused exit.

They really don't need to supply good evidence (the competent authorities may presume that third-country national does not fulfil, ... the conditions of duration of authorised stay within the territory of the Member States). The OP would need to show that they have been regularly in their country of residence. This could be considered 'credible evidence'.

(+1) Good point on the fact that both trips count towards the 90 days, it's important to stress that.

Mark Johnson: I agree the OP is in the wrong by overstaying and therefore must face some risk. By "good evidence" I intend here: it would not necessarily be evident to the relevant authorities (or desirable) that they should single out the OP for such an investigation.


Will the airport border control know I have overstayed and give me trouble?

They won't have a full record of all entries and exits in Schengen countries but they will know about previous entries and exits in Switzerland, at least from outside the Schengen area. Because crossings of internal Schengen borders are not systematically recorded, border guards cannot immediately be certain that you did not go to another country in the meantime but depending on how you entered Switzerland in the first place, it might still look like you might have spent a long time in the country or at least outside Portugal (more on that later).
If that's the case, reentering one week later is bound to look extremely suspicious, no matter what kind of story you told on exit. Consequently, you could be asked to describe your purpose and travels in more details than usual. Do you have a good answer for that? It's very easy to contradict yourself or sound unconvincing if you have to lie about all that. At that point, the overstay is only part of the problem, there are also serious questions on the purpose for your visits.

Could I say I have spent some of my time here in Italy/France? Will I overstayed despite no passport stamps and flag me up?

Swiss border guards cannot be certain that you did not go to another country in the meantime but beside being dangerous, pretending to have been in Italy or France achieves very little; 90 days in any 180-day period is the maximum amount of time you are allowed to spend in all Schengen countries outside Portugal. France and Italy count towards that limit.
The only thing that could make a difference is the date you first entered into Switzerland and how long you spent in Portugal since then. The police would not readily have a record of the trips between Portugal and Switzerland but it seems harder for you to pretend you went there without being able to produce any evidence (vs. a quick hop over the border with France).

"reentering one week later is bound to look extremely suspicious": bound to?  If it's Zurich or even Geneva, there must be thousands of residence permit holders passing through every day without having spent more than a few hours in Switzerland.  I don't suppose they would have any way of knowing that she hadn't arrived from Portugal immediately before leaving the Schengen area or wasn't going to travel there immediately after entering it.

As another EU resident, for me it is fairly common to fly out for a week then return. I've never been questioned over this. Never overstayed 90/180 in other countries though, and I have been told more questions are asked if you enter through not-your-resident-country.

@ave Yes, of course, it's not leaving for a week that's suspicious, it's leaving for a week after having seemingly stayed in the same country (not your country of residence) for 90+ days. I also don't expect them to be able to positively verify that the OP wasn't in transit to Portugal but that's a connection that makes little sense and I would at least ask. If they don't have a ticket to Portugal, they need a purpose and an explanation for the previous stay and everything can unravel fast.

@phoog Zurich, maybe, if they come from some of the farther destinations served by the LH group, Geneva, not so much except perhaps French or Italian (and obviously Swiss) residents. One thing that I feel is suspicious here is that Switzerland really doesn't make sense as a stopover between the UK and Portugal. It's only a minor hub, it's a very long connection for a short distance and there are so many cheap flights from the UK to Portugal.

"after having seemingly stayed in the same country": how would it seem so?  What record would there be of arrival in Switzerland?  It shouldn't be that exceptional to fly Swiss from Portugal to the UK, and there is a very significant Portuguese community in Geneva -- an easyJet hub -- and therefore plenty of connections with Portugal, easyJet and otherwise.

@phoog Good point, I somehow assumed the OP flew in from the UK but you're right that it would be a lot less suspicious if there is no record of the first entry. I still think flying Swiss from Portugal to the UK makes no sense at all. I am well aware of the Portuguese community in Geneva and the fact that there are plenty of cheap flights to Portugal from many places in Europe, it's just that the direct flights from the UK are so cheap that I would be surprised if many people did that.

AFAIK, easyJet still doesn't sell connecting flights or did they start doing that? So you're not getting a cheaper fare as you may with a full-service airline and it's even less attractive.

@phoog I edited the answer to clarify what I meant and somewhat weaken the conclusion as it's quite likely the OP entered Switzerland from Portugal in which case most of what I wrote would not apply.

@Relaxed I agree that flying through Geneva or even Zurich is not the most likely way to get from Portugal to the UK, but I suppose that it's not so unreasonable or uncommon as to raise red flags. I did a search yesterday with many affordable options through both, and of course there may be other factors leading to a choice of transit airport. I would also be mildly surprised if the Swiss computer system would flag someone even for several short trips from Switzerland to the UK with no other Schengen crossings, on a third country passport and a residence permit from a distant Schengen country.

I would be mildly surprised, but not entirely.  I was also surprised to learn as I was looking into this that Switzerland has enacted a law for analysis of asylum seekers' mobile phones; if this were extended to residence permit holders it would certainly change the analysis of the 90/180 rule for them.

Get a train to Basel and then walk across the bridge into Germany and you are back in the EU. If you time it for when all the German residents who work in Basel finish work for the day you can hide yourself in the crowd.

And then what? You are still within the Schengen Area and outside the country of residence (thus the 90/180 days rule still applies) of the OP, thus your suggested hiding 'yourself in the crowd' serves no purpose what so ever.

@MarkJohnson then you can have a train from Germany To Portugal - probably, via France and Spain. Or a bus. Or rent a car and drive to Portugal and a friend can drive it back...

@Mykola But nobody will care about that. They will want credible evidence that the OP was regularly in their country of residence for the previous months. The burdon of proof lies with the third-country national.

@MarkJohnson Is that really the case in these circumstances?

There is no risk at all. I have lived for more than 10 years in Switzerland with an EU passport, and I have crossed the swiss/french border many times a year. No one ever asked my identity when crossing the border.
So, as long as you haven't overstayed your EU visa you are safe. And yes, you can say you have crossed the border to France by car when traveling with friends safely. They won't have any records of it.
You might as well have arrived in Switzerland by plane 7 months ago, then taken a car back to Portugal only one week later. They wouldn't know and they have no interest in checking anyways. With a valid EU visa, only customs and taxes care where you live. Not immigration.

So,Are you telling the OP to lie? And yes, you can say you have crossed the border to France by car when traveling with friends safely. ? If they have suspect and they verify, you transform an overstay to a criminal offence.

This answer is not applicable: OP does not have an EU passport, but a Portuguese residence permit. You have the right to free movement, OP does not (only 90/180 outside of Portugal, which they have overstayed).

This is (likely) a wrong answer but it is an answer.

@ave but because nobody asks anyone's identity when crossing the border, border crossings are not recorded regardless of whether the person crossing has a right of free movement.

@Ave on top of that, Switzerland's implementation of the free movement agreement with the EU is somewhat more restrictive than the directive that applies everywhere else; an EU citizen who stays for longer than three months in Switzerland without obtaining a residence permit is overstaying.
